# Validation check to see if a string is next to another string (linewise)

Tags: python, python-3.7

```
------
Jordan
123
------
Che
379
------
Jaz
567
------
Sammy
908
```

As you can see the Username is on one line, and the password is on the next.

Im try to create a validation check that so when you enter a username, it then asks you to enter the correct corresponding password (the next line to the Username).

Comment: What part of what you want to achieve do you have a problem with? As a side note, it is definitely not recommended to store passwords in clear text.

Comment: It's stored in a py. file.

Comment: "Im try to create a validation check that so when you enter a username, it then asks you to enter the correct corresponding password (the next line to the Username)."

I used .find for the username, but how do i check that the user entered the corresponding password?

Comment: Share your code please